# Looping animations with jsanim

Tags: javascript, animation, frameworks

I have been using [jsanim](http://www.jsanim.com/) for the cration of a series of animations that are supposed to be looped after a specific time and animate two properties of only one element at the same time.

The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var manager = new jsAnimManager(40);

var bhosmokemov = manager.createAnimObject("bho_smoke");
var bhosmokefade = manager.createAnimObject("bho_smoke");

bhosmoke = document.getElementById("bho_smoke");

manager.registerPosition("bho_smoke");
bhosmoke.setPosition(-1003,305);

function smokeLoop() {
    bhosmokemov.add({property: Prop.position, to: new Pos(2000,303), duration: 25000,ease: jsAnimEase.parabolicNeg});
    bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.opacity, from: 0, to: 1, duration: 2500});
    bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.wait, duration: 1600});
    bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.opacity, from:1, to: 0, duration: 2500,    onComplete:smokeLoop});
}
</script>
```

What I was trying to achieve is to loop **smokeLoop()**, so that the complete chain of property animations that is contained within it, repeats itself forever. This approach is not working. Of course I could just use something like:

```
 function smokeLoop() {
    bhosmokemov.add({property: Prop.position, to: new Pos(2000,303), duration: 25000,ease: jsAnimEase.parabolicNeg, loop: 2;});
    bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.opacity, from: 0, to: 1, duration: 2500});
    bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.wait, duration: 1600});
    bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.opacity, from:1, to: 0, duration: 2500,    onComplete:smokeLoop});
}
```

But I would be only looping one of the property animations. How can I do to loop them all? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure why your first method does not work.  Maybe you should call some method to clear the animation queues of `bhoosmokemov` and `bhosmodefade` at the start of `smokeLoop`.

Comment: I don't know if you should use jsanim: it seems to be more complex than the animation system in jQuery and I don't know if it does anything more.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself to the problem. This is how it worked:

```
var manager = new jsAnimManager(40);


    var bhosmokemov = manager.createAnimObject("bho_smoke");
    var bhosmokefade = manager.createAnimObject("bho_smoke");

    var bhosmoke = document.getElementById("bho_smoke");

    manager.registerPosition("bho_smoke");


    var startbholoops = function () {
        bhosmoke.setPosition(-1103,305);
        bhosmokemov.add({property: Prop.position, to: new Pos(1000,305), duration: 10000,ease: jsAnimEase.parabolicNeg,  onComplete:startbholoops});
        bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.opacity, from: 0, to: 1, duration: 3500});
        bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.wait, duration:1600});
        bhosmokefade.add({property: Prop.opacity, from:1, to: 0, duration: 3500});
    }


        startbholoops();
```

Thanks  for your help toto, jsanim is actually a very good animation library  and offers some features that jquery doesn't. It is also smaller if you only want a couple of animations.